# two positive real numbers have their sum, product...

Tags: quadratics, real-numbers

Two positive real numbers have their sum,product and difference of the squares $(a^2-b^2)$ equal. Find those numbers.
It would be easy to solve if only two of these were mentioned, but I don't know how to incorporate all three (sum,pro,diff) in an equation

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange. Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for formatting your functions. Also please expand on your question. How did you attempt to solve the problem? How did you stumble on this?

Answer (score 2):

Let $a, b$ be two positive real numbers.
And we have $a+b = ab = (a^2-b^2) = (a+b)(a-b)$.

We have that $a-b=1$ since $a+b \neq 0$. Can you continue...